# IOS how to check whether the i finish looping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, for-loop, nsxmlparser

I have a `for` loop which is looping properly. But i want to check if the loop has finish looping, if yes i want to perform an action if no i want perform another action.

here is the codes:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [loadingview setHidden:NO];
    NSLog(@"Response recieved");

    output = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    deepsightSig = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    lastEl = [item_pass lastObject];

    for (int i = 0; i < item_pass.count; i++) {
      NSString *soapMessage = //soap message
      url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://abc/SWS/hellworld.asmx"];
      theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

      [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
      [theRequest addValue: @"https://www.hello.com/helloworld" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
      [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
      [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
      [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

      connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
      [connection start];
      if (i == item_pass.count - 1) {
        // this is the end of the loop
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dasdom I'm flagging your comment as "not constructive." Let's be inclusive and welcoming to beginner programmers.

Comment: @JackLawrence You are correct and I was wrong. I removed my comment and the close vote.

Comment: @JackLawrence And instead I have posted an answer.

Comment: @dasdom Thanks, just saw it (great answer) and upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let us break this down together. First we take a closer look at a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
}
```

There are three parts within the parentheses.

1. `int i = 0`: Even without any reading of the documentation or any book about programming, this looks like the initial setting of the loop variable `i`.
2. `i < 5`: This looks like some kind of condition. The loop variable `i` should be smaller than 5. This could mean that the loop finishes when the loop variable becomes greater or equal to 5.
3. `i++`: Uh, this is strange. But it becomes much clearer when we replace it with an equivalent expression. `i++` is equivalent with `i = i + 1`. Now it becomes clear that this is the statement that is executed **after** each loop but **before** the end condition (`i < 5`) is evaluated.

Ok, let us assume we still don't really understand what a loop is and what is does. To get a better understanding, we could add a breakpoint in the loop and let the debugger help us to understand it. Or we can add an log statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    NSLog(@"i: %d", i);
}
```

This produces the output:

```
i: 0
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
```

And it tells us that the loop variable is accessible from within the loop. Not let us change the code in the loop to only log during the first and the last iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        NSLog(@"This might be the first iteration: i = %d", i);
    } else if (i == 5 - 1) {
        NSLog(@"This might be the last iteration: i = %d", i);
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
This might be the first iteration: i = 0
This might be the last iteration: i = 4
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add BOOL instance variable in ViewController to check if loop is over by updating the variable in the end of the loop. Like

```
if (i == item_pass.count - 1) {
    loopFinished = YES; // Added Variable to check loop if finished or not
}
```

Comment: this code is put inside for loop or outside for loop?

Comment: inside the loop at last

Comment: is it correct? i have updated the codes above. please check. ty!

Comment: hm, @channi, if you change it to `loopFinished = i == item_pass.count - 1` it could save nearly 2/3 of code lines!

Comment: Yes it is much better approach but only for understanding purpose I used the if statement

Comment: The codes does not reach the last index. it straight away go into the codes

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for the finish of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < item_pass.count; i++) {
//...
}
//this is the end of the loop
```

Or I'm missing something in your question

Comment: i need to check for the end of loop to perform another action.

Comment: but #2
for (int i = 0; i < item_pass.count; i++) {
//...
if (i == item_pass.count - 1) {
        // this is the end of the loop #1
      }
}
//this is the end of the loop #1
will be executed right after #1. Idon’t see why you need this check inside loop

Comment: i have two method. one in view did load to launch a connection to my web service. i did a loop inside the soap message as i want to enter different parameter into it. when one loop executed, the method will go into nsxmlparser documentdidend method which will do a counting. after all the loops have finish in view did load, i want to perform another action.